# Could not remove docker.io images

Tags: docker

Initially I installed docker.io on Fedora 21 and have pulled images like docker.io/ubuntu and docker.io/hello-world.

Later system is upgraded to Fedora 22. docker.io is removed and docker-engine is reinstalled.

Both docker.io/ubuntu and docker.io/hello-world cannot be removed. (I have removed all containers, so no containers dependent on them).

it's throwing errors:

`Error response from daemon: No such repository: ubuntu
Error response from daemon: No such repository: ubuntu
Error response from daemon: No such repository: hello-world
Error response from daemon: No such repository: hello-world`

Before upgrading, I was using docker 1.8.x, now using latest 1.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove images files from /var/lib/docker/graphs:

`rm * -rf`